# Check if extends jTextFormattedField is empty

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

I have one extends jFormattedTextField and in this field, I have a method to verify if it is empty, but in jTextField it works, but in jFormattedTextField no.

As I pass the fields on my frame:

```
RVDFormattedTextField[] obrigatoriosFTF = new RVDFormattedTextField[1];
    private void setaObrigatorios() {
        obrigatoriosFTF[0] = rvfCNPJ;
    }
if (RVDFormattedTextField.isEmpty(obrigatoriosFTF)) {
            Mensagem.aviso("Preencha os campos obrigatórios (*).", this);
        } else {
```

Method in jFormattedTextField:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(RVDFormattedTextField[] campos) {
        Boolean ok = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < campos.length; i++) {
            if (Formatacao.removerFormatacao(campos[i].getText()).trim().isEmpty()) {
                ok = true;
                if (campos[i].isEditable()) {
                    campos[i].setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51)));
                }
            } else {
                campos[i].setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            }
        }
        return ok;
    }
```

Does not show errors, tried to put a sout in the method and debug however nothing happens.

Method removerFormatacao

```
    public static String removerFormatacao(String dado) {
        String retorno = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < dado.length(); i++) {
            if (dado.charAt(i) != '.' && dado.charAt(i) != '/' && dado.charAt(i) != '-' && dado.charAt(i) != '(' && dado.charAt(i) != ')') {
                retorno = retorno + dado.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return (retorno);
    }
```

Method formatarCNPJ (mask)

```
    public static void formatarCnpj(JFormattedTextField campo) {
        try {
            MaskFormatter m = new MaskFormatter();
            m.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
            m.setMask("##.###.###/####-##");
            campo.setCaretPosition(0);
            campo.setFormatterFactory(null);
            campo.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(m));
            campo.setValue(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

I tried to remove these two methods, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, which mask is used on the JFormattedText and how is the `Formatacao.removerFormatacao` implementation?

Comment: I runned your code and worked fine. Which is the specific use case that you are testing and what is not working?

Comment: If I hit the save button, he should check the empty fields and paint them, but in my code he doesn't do that with formatted, but in normal textfield it's work..

Comment: I tested with the original JFormattedTextField class and worked fine. Did you overrode some method in your subclass?

Comment: Oh my god, got it now the problem, my if is if ```(RVDFormattedTextField.isEmpty(obrigatoriosFTF) || RVDTextField.isEmpty(obrigatorios) || !vCheckBox())``` and by giving validation error in the first field, it no longer runs the rest of if, I'm dumb kkkk, thanks for your help.